# Best design for Multiple TableViews for iOS application

Tags: ios

i have a tabbed application (an application with a tab bar in the bottom)

and each tap will contain some sort of tableview.

each tableview is to represent some sort of information. (pictures below)

[image][image]

for example, the first tableview is to show the services that the user are willing to do. And the second tableview to show the requests that he got for some sort of services that he could do.

i dont feel that what i have achieved so far is good and i dont feel the user will see the difference from the two tableview as is.

how can i create multiple tableviews in my application such that they look good and the user can distinguish them according their look and without making them too different from each other?

Comment: Do you navigate from the first tableview to the second tableview?

Comment: no, the navigation will be according to the tab bar below

Comment: Ok - is there a relationship between the first tableview and the second tableview?

Comment: yes there is. SOME of the second tableview cell are the requested services from the first tableview

Comment: So just for clarity - if I tap the card in the first screenshot I will now see the second screenshot?

Comment: no, not at all.

Comment: This is confusing. Everyone who has responded thinks you tap the card in the first table to go to the second table. What happens when you tap the card in the first table?

Comment: shows you a detailed information about the card in the tableview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would make more sense if you group the tabs and define if particular command is intended for navigation or option. The way I understand the profile view is list of "user selected services" and the requested services view shows "all request based on user selected services". Then if that's the logic, its more sensible to move these two commands on top and no need for the tab "Services".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the subview, just change the background color with the lightest variation of the view primary colors (I understand from your design / I suppose you have different colors for the views and if you don't have, I suggest this change too). If you don't want to have more than one color, add some icons.

Comment: which subviews i didn't get you? the Cells you mean? and thank you for your response

Comment: @AliAlebrahim I understand you have in the second tab services and you named them "some sort of tableview". After you click the arrow, a more detailed view is displayed (a subview I thought). So I suggested to change the background for it.

Comment: @AliAlebrahim Can you explain more detailed what you need to need to be different? When you say "multiple tableviews" you want to say you have more categories like services displayed in tableviews or you have more levels?

Comment: i want the two tableviews to be different in their look yet to be elegant and to have the same feel in the application. not like a very major difference.

Answer (score 0):

As Splatz explained I also thought you are navigating from first to second tableview. Is it possible to expand the same table to view your two results? That will easily differentiate both of your two results. I have created a solutions, please check herehttps://au.pinterest.com/pin/180284791312504675/ (*forgive me, my browser is old and I'm not able to upload the image for reference in ux-stackexchange.) I hope this helps? If this solutions will not work, please explain the constraint, so that I might come up with different solution. Thank you Ali.